# Does Oracle sdo_geom tolerance impact computational time

Tags: oracle, performance, geometry, gis, computational-geometry

I have a project with some geometry functions (partly in Oracle, partly in other DBs). Most important are: sdo_area, sdo_length, distance.

What I am interest in: is how Oracles and sdo_area performance (that is time of calculation) depends on tolerance?

Say if I decrease tolerance from 5 cm to 1 m the speed* of the functions should increase - or it's independent (in general case, of course).

- memory consumption, CPU utilization is also important.

Comment: Did you benchmark this yourself?

Comment: hi @arve0, unfortunately I hardly have some good statistics to share, so in my apps it looks like tolerance impact is neglect-able.